# How to create a speech bubble with css only

Tags: html, css, geometry, css-shapes

I want to make a speech bubble and I'm almost achieving my goal. Just a simple thing that is driving me crazy.

Check [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelsantos/us6foy1u/) to see my code and what I need.

I tried this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="date">
    03 Fev 14
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.date{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: #00a1e0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.date:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 6px 0;
    border-color: #00a1e0 transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

As you can see, at the moment I have a triangle with two angles of 45degrees, and I want it to have an angle of 90degrees on top aligned to the left.

How can I achieve this without the use of an additional image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the last value for `border-width`. Try this:

```
.date:after {
    border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

```css
.date {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #00a1e0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.date:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-color: #00a1e0 transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h3>What I want: (image)</h3>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/wlyK9EN.png">
<br>
<br>
<h3>What I have:</h3>
<div class="date">
  03 Fev 14
</div>
```

Comment: @rafaelmsantos np mate glad to help u